# FILENOTFOUND Exception while reading File from file uri for Recent file location and google drive file location in android

Tags: android

```
public class PdfToBase64 {

    public static String getActualPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

        final String[] split = docId.split(":");
        final String type = split[0];

        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                return Environment.getStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
        }
        return Environment.getRootDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String filePath = getActualPath(this, data.getData());

        File pdfFile = new File(filePath);

        try {

            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pdfFile.getPath()));

            pdfBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TFGTESTINGPanE", e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

**MY DEVICE is Android 11 and 12**

below 3 Uri location are return from data.getData() but for drive and recent file location showing fileNotFoundExecption while reading the file and perfectly working with External and internal storage location

**1. Selected file from External/Internal path location:**
from this path working properly

content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2F**Java%20.pdf**

**2. Selected file from google drive location:**
FileNotFound Exection

content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/**acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3DGKVQVPeUy8YACTP3yosCu14qFMpPUAUvpmE_n27UcH0XrcgXcBFfjHrOnO2h**

**3.Selected file from Recent file location:**
FileNotFound Exection

content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%**3A1000004084**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
        InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
        byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
        bytes = is.readAllBytes();
        is.close();
        panPdfBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It will work for recent, internal, external, GoogleDrive location
**getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData())**